# Drag And Drop textview on imageview in android

Tags: android

I tried my best can anyone help to **drag and drop textview** on imageview in android

my xml with frame layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/golden_gate" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

    android:padding="12dip"

    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"

    android:text="Golden Gate" />

</FrameLayout>
```

i tried drag and drop text as below as i have used here linear layout the text is dragging in some part only not on image

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class DragNDropActivity extends Activity {
        private View selected_item = null;
        private int offset_x = 0;
        private int offset_y = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.vg);
        vg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                switch(event.getActionMasked())
                                {
                                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                                int x = (int)event.getX() - offset_x;
                                                int y = (int)event.getY() - offset_y;
                        int w = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() - 100;
                        int h = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() - 100;
                        if(x > w)
                            x = w;
                        if(y > h)
                            y = h;
                                         LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                         lp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
                                                selected_item.setLayoutParams(lp);
                                                break;
                                        default:
                                                break;
                                }
                                return true;
                        }
   });
      TextView img = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                switch(event.getActionMasked())
                                {
                                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                                offset_x = (int)event.getX();
                                                offset_y = (int)event.getY();
                                                selected_item = v;
                                                break;
                                        default:
                                                break;
                                }

                                return false;
                        }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: i used frame layout n also linear layout but i cant drag and drop text on image

Comment: please give me idea about which build api level you can used?or your target api level i have one demo for api level 11 or higher version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Frame Layout** it should figure out what you want.

Comment: can you please post your layout xml

Comment: you code is working on my eclipse now but with one of my drawables

Comment: if i am using frame layout i cannot drag and drop textview on image

Answer (score 0):

Use **RelativeLayout** like this. Note:You may place it inside your ParentView

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="100dp" android:id="@+id/photoframe" android:layout_height="320dp" android:layout_weight="1.0">
        <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:id="@+id/framephoto" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ImageView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="188dp"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

inside your layout.xml. By using **Relative** you can **drag your textview over your image.**

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one....

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">        
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:scaleType="center" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="#AA000000" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:text="Golden Gate"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I checked it with my eclipse.And let me know is it working or not.